# How to create a SpatRaster from dataframe

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, terra

To create a SpatRaster from dataframe with large dataframe / Raster objects some tools like `rasterize()`, `sp::gridded()` seems very slow, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r1 <- rast(f)
r.df <- terra::as.data.frame(r1, na.rm = FALSE) 

r2 <- setValues(r1, as.matrix(r.df))
```

Or depending on context first create the SpatRaster and then use `values<-` or `setValues`

```
r.df <- terra::as.data.frame(r1, xy=TRUE, na.rm = FALSE) 
r3 <- rast(r1, nlyr=ncol(r.df))
values(r3) <- as.matrix(r.df)
names(r3) <- colnames(r.df)

r3
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 90, 95, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source      : memory 
#names       :        x,        y, elevation 
#min values  : 5.745833, 49.44583,       141 
#max values  : 6.529167, 50.18750,       547
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I was processing 130 files (dimensions  : 2017, 2074, 130  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)) and save them as dataframe (it was faster in this step), but then later convert all of them back to SpatRaster was time consuming (even the as.matrix() step), so I write all as .tif and load with terra::rast();  Superfast then (3 seconds) and .tif takes less space in disk compared with .rds of .fst; also thanks for the terra:: package!

Answer (score 0):

Generate the dataframe from a SpatRaster

```
### Load a raster file 
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
plot(r)
class(r)

### Convert the SpatRaster to a dateframe
r.df <- terra::as.data.frame(r, xy = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE) 
class(r.df)
head(r.df)
```

To convert back from dataframe to SpatRaster, start with empty raster

```
### create empty raster
crs_ref <- "EPSG:4326"
empty_r <- rast(res=0.008333333, nlyr= 1, # number of layers according the number of cols of dataframe
                extent= ext(r), # can be other object extent like a shapefile, etc
                crs= crs_ref)

### fill the empty raster with cell values
rast_ <- init(empty_r, fun= r.df[, 3])

### adjust the name
names(rast_) <- names(r.df[3])

### plot
plot(rast_)
```